# How to hide path location in Run Window in Pycharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Today is my first day with Python and I started Using Pycharm Community edition in my Mac. This IDE is really good but one thing annoyed me a lot.
Is there any way I can remove the whole path from showing every time I run a program?

Wanted to remove this Path :

```
/Users/rajvivan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/bin/python /Users/rajvivan/PycharmProjects/Python/App.py
```

[image]

Would just like to see the exact responses from the program:

```
First Day in Python
Hello, World!
```

Comment: You could just move the project folder under C:/projects. PyCharm Projects default location is the one you see, but any folder can be a PyCharm project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to hide it completely, you can only make it appear folded by adding a pattern like `/bin/python` in File | Settings | Editor | General | Console, Fold console lines that contain.

Comment: Thank you It did solve the Problem.
This is what My output looks like

First Day in Python
Hello, World!

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 2):

In watching the [Bro Code channel](https://youtu.be/XKHEtdqhLK8) on Youtube,  he changed the font color of the file path so that it's camouflaged. His words not mine just thought I'd share.   I can't find the exact area that he's referring to as of yet so if someone else see's it,  please share for the rest of us.

Thank you

Based on Bro Code's response I believe the attached is what he was referring too.  This is what I came up with.  If you goto Help>Find Action>output you'll see Console//System output. Change/Camouflage the color codes as in the picture.  Hopefully this works for others.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the path into

```
File | Settings | Editor | General | Console`
```

and paste it as new `Fold console` lines, it will hide the line as `<1 internal line>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Code Runner" extension.

Steps:

- Install the "Code Runner" extension.
- Go to Settings -> Extensions -> Run Code configuration -> uncheck Show Execution message.

Then, run the code and you will see clean output in the Output tab.